# Apache's mod_rewrite taking over everything

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried looking through Apache's documentation to get the answer to this question, but I have to admit my ignorance with regard to a lot of the little intricacies going on with mod_rewrite.

Basically, I have a rewrite rule that's doing too much. I only want two types of URLs to be redirected to index.php:

```
http://domain.com/pathone/*
```

and

```
http://domain.com/pathtwo/*
```

However, what I have now is rewriting everything, as you'd expect from the rule below. Which means I can't access files like `http://domain.com/about.php` without being redirected back to `index.php`.

Here's what I have in `.htaccess` at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

I was thinking I could just change RewriteRule to

```
RewriteRule ^/(pathone|pathtwo)/(.*) index.php [L]
```

but that just seemed to break everything :/

I would greatly appreciate any help with this matter :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed a better RewriteRule, as expected. I changed it to

```
RewriteRule ^(pathone/|pathtwo/)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ index.php [L]
```

and it seems to be working. Although, for some reason, some files are returning 500 errors when the file does in fact exist... a question for another day perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The RewriteRule is the action taken based on the above conditions.  The last RewriteCond stated that anything non-index.php will have the below action taken.  You need to edit this Condition, not the action.